# Odoo 10 : How to remove the random values from drop down list of a many2one field?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i have these random values in my drop down menu : [image]

I would like to have an option in GUI to delete these values. How to achieve this?

Comment: what have u tried till now?

Comment: Where do the random values even come from? What are you doing?

Comment: i tried to add ondelete=cascade in my many2one field but no success !

Comment: @not_a_bot_no_really_82353  : i added those random values and now i want to delete them

Comment: So they are user generated and not random? Why can't you just press del?

Comment: Where is  the delete button?

Comment: Why you are entering random values if you want to delete it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a menu entry for manage the devices records and you will be ok to delete the ones that you don't need anymore